# Get mean of 3 greatest value in a Bigquery Array

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

Suppose I have this table called table1 in Bigquery where x and y are an array, how can I get the mean of the 3 greatest x and y for each time? Thank you!

Table 1:

```
Time                           x                     y
00:01:00                     -1.05                  1.23
                             1.456                  2.432
                             1.890                  1.456
                             -0.345                 1.356
                             1.2345                 0.9853
                             1.2344                 0.9857
00:02:00                     2.124                  1.3564
                             1.345                  2.4542
                             -0.9823                3.2343
                             1.231                  1.3453
```

Desired:

```
Time                    avg_x                                  avg_y
00:01:00              (Average of 3 greatest x at 00:01:00)  (Average of 3 greatest x at 00:01:00)
00:02:00              (Average of 3 greatest x at 00:02:00)  (Average of 3 greatest x at 00:02:00)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION avg_array(arr ANY TYPE) AS ((
  SELECT AVG(val) FROM(
    SELECT val FROM UNNEST(arr) val ORDER BY val DESC LIMIT 3)
  )
);
SELECT time, 
  avg_array(x) avg_x,
  avg_array(y) avg_y
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply to your sample data - result is

```
Row time        avg_x               avg_y    
1   00:01:00    1.5268333333333333  1.748    
2   00:02:00    1.5666666666666669  2.3483
```

More generic version (below) allows you to pass how many top elements to account

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION avg_array(arr ANY TYPE, cnt INT64) AS ((
  SELECT AVG(val) FROM(
    SELECT val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY val DESC) pos FROM UNNEST(arr) val
  )
  WHERE pos <= cnt
));
SELECT time, 
  avg_array(x, 3) avg_x,
  avg_array(y, 3) avg_y
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail Berlyant. If I would like to obtain the mean of the greatest and 3rd greatest value in each array without the 2nd greatest value, is there any way?

Comment: sure. that's why i gave you generic version - just change `pos <= cnt` to `pos in (1,3)`, obviously you could adjust avg_array function to get not the count but rather list of which elements you want to calc average. hope you can do this exercise by yourself :o)

Comment: Thank you so much! It is my first time using sql in general!

Comment: great. happy we helped!